# Seeking a variation on `zip`

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays of the following shapes that I would like to combine.

arrays:

```rb
arr1 = [["apple", "aardvark"], ["banana", "beach"]]
arr2 = ['A', 'B']
```

desired result:

```rb
[["apple", "aardvark", "A"], ["banana", "beach", "B"]]
```

I'm wondering what would be an idiomatic way to do this in Ruby.

I can obviously just do a loop, such as

```rb
i = 0
while i < arr1.length
  arr1[i] << arr2[i]
  i += 1
end
```

But I'm wondering if there's an elegant one-liner I'm just overlooking. `zip` is the closest I could think of, but it's not quite there:

```rb
arr1.zip(arr2)
# => [[["apple", "aardvark"], "A"], [["banana", "beach"], "B"]]
```

Comment: Please elaborate "shapes". Is `arr1` always an array of arrays that do not contain arrays? Is `arr2` always an array of element that are not arrays?

Comment: Note that whenever the two elements being zipped are the same size, you could use `Array#transpose` instead: `[arr1, arr2].transpose.map { |e1,e2| [*e1, e2] }` (though the latter creates two intermediate arrays as compared to `zip`'s one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatten each array after zipping:

```rb
arr1.zip(arr2).map(&:flatten)
```

Alternatively, [`Enumerable#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) takes an optional block, in which case it invokes the block for each combination, without returning a value though.

Thus, you could write it as follows, which is slightly less elegant:

```rb
[].tap { |res| arr1.zip(arr2) { |a, b| res.push(a + [b]) } }
```

Comment: `flatten` works, provided that (as in the example) none of the elements of `arr1` or `arr2` are arrays.

Comment: @CarySwoveland What do you mean? `arr1` elements are arrays. And it works.

Comment: @Amadan, what I meant to write is the substance of my first comment on the question, but I got it wrong. I'll fix that.

Comment: I meant that `flatten` works provided that (as in the example) none of the elements of `arr1` contain arrays and none of the elements of `arr2` are arrays. If, for example, `arr1 = [[1,[2]], [3,4]]` and `arr2 = ['A', ['B']]`, presumably the desired return value would be `[[1,[2],'A'], [3,4,['B']]`, not `[[1,2,'A'], [3,4,'B']]`.

Comment: It would still work though. `arr1 = ["a", ["B"]]; arr2 = [[1, 2], 3]; arr1.zip(arr2).map(&:flatten)` gives the correct `[["a", 1, 2], ["B", 3]]`.

Comment: @Amadan, the question is not clear on that point, and it may be moot.

Answer (score 2):

You can add each element in arr2 to arr1 according to its corresponding index using `map`, `with_index` and `+`:

```
p arr1.map.with_index { |e, i| e + [arr2[i]] }
# [["apple", "aardvark", "A"], ["banana", "beach", "B"]]
```

Or zipping arr1 with arr2 and mapping the sum of the elements in arr2 as an array with the elements in arr1:

```
p arr1.zip(arr2).map { |a, b| [*a, b] }
# [["apple", "aardvark", "A"], ["banana", "beach", "B"]]
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you went with `a + [b]` rather than `a << b`?  I'm curious about tradeoffs.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that `a << b` will modify the original `arr1`.

Comment: That looks nice @CarySwoveland, I'll edit. And yes pjs, `+` for returning the third array from the concatenation of both others. In this case, it'd mutate `arr1`.